# Why does not a tooltip work in WPF 2010?

Tags: xaml, tooltip

I have a texbox. I would like to show a tooltip when a user brings a mouse on the Textbox.
I write such code, but my program just breaks and VS 2010 gives a window of report.
This is my xaml-code:

```
 <TextBox Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="231,17,0,0" 
  Name="Student_textBox"         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" 
  GotFocus="Student_textBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="Student_textBox_LostFocus"
  TabIndex="1"   
  KeyDown="Student_textBox_KeyDown" ToolTip="Hello, Student!"/>
```

Why does not a tooltip work in WPF 2010?
How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that piece of XAML. Maybe the problem is in one of the event handlers instead (Student_textBox_GotFocus/Student_textBox_LostFocus/Student_textBox_KeyDown)?

What does the error report say? Can you post the error message and possibly a stack trace?

Comment: You don't need top post all your code - just the error message you get, if possible.